# Azure Active Directory delegate permissions new created application not listed

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I tried to grant delegated permissions to webApi using azure.portal.com. 
Two web App/API application was register on azure AD. When i try to use 'Settings->RequiredPermissions->Add->Select an API' i not see my created application in list.

Same problem for old azure portal described on [Granting native application access to web application](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/2b03b3c8-47ab-458e-9872-cfd4bc5b678b/granting-native-application-access-to-web-application?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

But new portal not fixed with previous solution.

Could anyone help, please ?

Comment: If you use management portal, could you set the required permission for your web app?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure AD app registration blades in portal.azure.com are currently not creating a `servicePrincipal` in the tenant when you register your application.  This means that the API you create will not show up in the list of apps to select from.  More detail in this [blog post](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/10/04/provision-an-app-created-on-portal-azure-com-in-your-own-tenant/)